# grails activemq application doesn't work for jelastic paas

Tags: grails, activemq-classic, apache-tomee, jelastic

Trying to deploy my **grails** app to **jelastic** environment and having a proper TomEE app server configured and all the plugins related to activemq I got the following exception on the server:

```
INFO: For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org
2016-03-06 20:04:17,194 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'myBrokerService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.activemq.usage.TempUsage.getStore()Lorg/apache/activemq/store/kahadb/plist/PListStore;
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myBrokerService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.activemq.usage.TempUsage.getStore()Lorg/apache/activemq/store/kahadb/plist/PListStore;
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.activemq.usage.TempUsage.getStore()Lorg/apache/activemq/store/kahadb/plist/PListStore;
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService.ensureSystemUsageHasStore(XBeanBrokerService.java:72)
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService.afterPropertiesSet(XBeanBrokerService.java:56)
    ... 5 more
```

On my local environment I use IntelliJ with the embedded tomcat and tomEE servers and it works properly. I suppose the issue is related to the fact that activemq doesn't have enough rights in order to create some files on the disk. Unfortunetly I'm not able to figure out where is the problem. Any advise is highly appreciated.

Comment: Based on the NoSuchMethodError, I would say that ActiveMQ Java libraries version on the server does not match the version you are using locally

Comment: Are you using the embedded ActiveMQ plugin?

Comment: @droggo: Dependencies that i use in the project: compile 'org.apache.activemq:activemq-core:5.7.0'
    compile 'org.apache.activemq:activemq-spring:5.7.0'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-beans:4.0.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.apache.xbean:xbean-spring:4.1'

Comment: which version of Grails?  2, 3?

Comment: @Arjang: Grails 2.2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find below the solution that works for Jelastic (tomcat 7, java7, grails 2.2.4) environment:

BuildConfig.groovy:

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:jms:1.3'
compile 'org.apache.activemq:activemq-core:5.7.0'
compile 'org.apache.xbean:xbean-spring:4.1'
```

resources.groovy:

```
import org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector
import org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService
import org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory

beans = {

tcpConnector(TransportConnector,uri:'tcp://localhost:61616'){}

connectors(ArrayList,[ref('tcpConnector')]){}
myBrokerService(XBeanBrokerService){bean->
    myBrokerService.useJmx = false
    myBrokerService.persistent = true
    myBrokerService.dataDirectory = 'my-activemq_data'
    myBrokerService.transportConnectors = ref('connectors')
}
amqConnectionFactory(org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory) {
    brokerURL = 'vm://localhost'
}

jmsConnectionFactory(SingleConnectionFactory) { bean ->
    targetConnectionFactory = ref(amqConnectionFactory)
 }
}
```

Embedded activemq started without any issues.